# How to choose which video output to use?

Tags: gnome, hdmi, wayland, displayport

I installed Ubuntu 22.04 on a computer that has a Display Port output and an HDMI output. Both outputs belong to the integrated graphic card.

By default the image only comes out of the Display Port, the HDMI isn't used. I want to change that. I want to tell GNOME to use the HDMI instead and shut down the Display Port. I searched the settings but couldn't find anything relevant. I searched the BIOS but there are no option to enable/disable these outputs. How can I do that?

I am using Wayland, which is the default on this version of Ubuntu.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.
Using the drm_info command I noticed the HDMI output was marked as disconnected even though it was plugged. This pointed to a driver issue, not a config issue. I fixed it by upgrading to a newer kernel.